# How to index and search on LocalDateTime MultiField

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a field of type `LocalDateTime`. I want to perform the wildcard and the range searches on this field. Initially, I defined it as:

```
// @formatter:off
@Field(
    name = "submission_date",
    type = FieldType.Date,
    format = DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second_fraction
)
// @formatter:on
private LocalDateTime submissionDate;
```

When I indexed a Document, `GET https://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping` returned the generated mapping as:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },        
        "submission_date": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And `GET https://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?q=*:*` returned:

```
"_source": {
    "_class": "someclass",
    "submission_date": "2022-11-17T00:00:00.000"
}
```

But I performed wildcard on it I got an error saying `Can only use wildcard queries on keyword, text and wildcard fields - not on [submission_date] which is of type [date]`.

So I used `MultiField` as:

```
@MultiField(
    mainField = @Field(
        name = "submission_date",
        type = FieldType.Date,
        format = DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second_fraction
    ),
    otherFields = @InnerField(
        suffix = "verbatim",
        type = FieldType.Keyword,
        format = DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second_fraction
    )
)
// @formatter:on
private LocalDateTime submissionDate;
```

Next after recreating the index when I indexed the Document again, the `GET https://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping` returned the generated mapping as:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },        
        "submission_date": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And `GET https://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?q=*:*` returned:

```
"_source": {
    "_class": "someclass",    
    "submission_date": 1668623400000
}
```

Clearly, the `submission_date` is not formatted as `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

Then when I performed the search, I got an error that says: `No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.time.LocalDateTime]` from `org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound`.

When this error occurred I was searching as

```
Mono<SearchResponse> response = elasticsearchOperations.searchForPage(query, MyClass.class)
```

But when I changed it to

```
Mono<SearchResponse> response = elasticsearchOperations.searchForPage(query, AllDocuments.class, IndexCoordinates.of("my_index"))
```

by following this [blog-post](https://www.sothawo.com/category/programming/java/spring/spring-data-elasticsearch/), I got the result as `{submission_date=1668623400000, id=7v8yT4UBHcWU9D_4JE6L}`.

I am looking for the right way to achieve searching on this type of field where I will be able to perform both wildcard and range queries. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for tracking a moment. That class lacks the context of an offset or time zone. For a specific point on the timeline, use `Instant`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the application does not need neither offset nor timezone. That is why `LocalDateTime` is used.

Comment: Your long number value appears to be a count since first moment of 1970 as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. As I said before, the appropriate type would be `Instant`, not `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Indeed, this 1668623400000 represents Thursday, November 17, 2022 12:00:00 AM in my local timezone IST. I am going to use instant. But I am still curious why the representation changed from "2022-11-17T00:00:00.000" to 1668623400000, when I used `@MultiField` instead of `@Field`.

Comment: Also, what about using `ZonedDateTime` with the server timezone, instead of `Instant`?